# I need a DB in my windows phone app(mango) - How can I put a DB in the sandbox and use it

Tags: sql-server, windows-phone-7.1

I found some articles in the net telling that the mango version may have a sqlserver version for windows phone.

So my question is: Is there a way to have a db in my sandbox.

how can I build the DB and how can I comunicate with it (add delete and edit...)

I would relly like to work with sqlserver(local) ... but if you have other ideas, i'd like to hear about them as well.

Thanks
Asaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are talking about [SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) (an [embedded database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database)).

[Derik Whittaker](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/default.aspx) has a series of blogposts about that:

- [Using SQL CE On WP7 Mango–Getting Started](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/07/21/using-sql-ce-on-wp7-mango-getting-started.aspx)
- [Using SQL CE On WP7 Mango–Working with Associations](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/07/23/using-sql-ce-on-wp7-mango-working-with-associations.aspx)
- [Using SQL CE On WP7 Mango–Working with Indexes](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2011/07/24/using-sql-ce-on-wp7-mango-working-with-indexes.aspx)

Comment: I've looked for the shortest way to make "SELECT * FROM TABLE" work. At the time sqlite, despite its limitation, did the work. Your solution seemed(never had time to test it) too complicated and now I hope that wp8 SDK have some sqlite like solution ... I really like the idea of a file like mdb,txt,sdf etc... so backup is easy.